# Convert jQuery recursive animate to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, requestanimationframe

I need time precision during an animation divided into steps.

The progress bar’s width is increased every 100ms by 20 pixels. I use jQuery’s `animate()` to animate the width.

Logging `Date.now()`, it’s clear that the time changes and it is not precise.

http://jsfiddle.net/trustweb/az3aE/23/

```
function animateProgress() {
    console.log(Date.now() - progressTime);
    progressTime = Date.now();

    progress_width = $(progress).width();

    if (progress_width < progressLimit) {
        $(progress).animate(
            { width: '+=20' }, '' + progressTime, "linear", animateProgress
        );
    }
}
```

I’ve been [reading about `requestAnimationFrame`](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/), and I guess it’s the right way; how can I convert the function above to use `requestAnimationFrame`, or achieve precise timing in some other way?

Comment: Does your real-world use case have something fancier than widening a line? (Because for the example you show I really don't understand why you need to be more precise - if you actually need to log the time in order to notice the imprecision it's really not very imprecise.)

Comment: @nnnnnn i have a complex DOM and yes, i just need to draw a line, but performing several check during each loop. the log time is very  imprecise since in this example the latency is incremental and in a long time it is going to matter

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need `requestAnimationFrame`. Use a transition instead and `setInterval`:

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById("progress");
var start = new Date();

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var t = new Date() - start;

    if (t < 500) {
        progressBar.style.width = (t * 20 / 100 | 0) + "px";
    } else {
        progressBar.style.width = "100px";
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 100);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rninty/sa99L/3/) (if I understand you correctly – your jsFiddle doesn’t have any elements involved, so it’s hard to tell)

Comment: `setInterval` is the "most precise" of the available JS timing tools, but it's important to note that even [`setInterval` experiences significant drift over time](http://www.goat1000.com/2011/03/23/how-accurate-is-window.setinterval.html). Some OS:Browser combinations do better than others, but there is no Javascript method that will give you access to reliable millisecond-level precision. For the sake of the OPs question, I can't imagine that he needs anything better than this, but it's worth keeping in mind that you cannot rely on javascript timing mechanisms for highly precise applications.

Comment: @BenD: You can for this; although it’s not guaranteed to update at precise intervals, it’s guaranteed to be accurate to the appropriate width of a precise timing (because I’m using “delta animation” or whatever people call it now).

Comment: @minitech i am not sure about this approach, can you apply your solution to the first jsfiddle? i need to perorm checks every cycle.

Comment: @Mike: Use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`, then. The calculation remains the same.